# Why doesn't R being Archemedian imply Axiom of Completeness?/Why doesn't the Archemedian property imply completeness in $R$?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I was trying to see if I could prove the following:
If $R$ is Archemedian, then there exists a supremum for all non-empty, bounded above subsets of $R$. I got stumped and looked it up only to find out that this isn't true. The only answer I found was to the affect of "Q is Archemedian and it is not complete."

From what I've done so far this is the closest thing I have to a reason as to why this isn't true: Let $A \subset R$ and be non empty and bounded above. For some upper bound, $t\in R$, $a \leq t $ for all $a$ in $A$.
$$0 \leq t-a$$ Then, by our assumption of $R$ being Archemedian, there exists a $n_0\in N$ such that $\frac{1}{n_0}<t-a$. With that inequality we can then write $a<t-\frac{1}{n_0}$. This implies we've found another upper bound for A that is smaller than the one we started with originally. This seems to hold for any upper bound of A and implies we can always find a smaller upper bound for any upper bound.

Is this thought process correct in why we can't show completeness purely through the Archemedian property of $R$? Also, are there any assumptions I can add that could possibly make this possible? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, consider a counterexample: the field $\mathbb{Q}$ is Archimedean but very not complete.

Comment: Your argument holds only when $0<t-a$ and not when $0=t-a$.

Comment: I find that it helps to work through concrete examples.  Consider $A = \{ x \in \Bbb R \mid x^2 \lt 2 \} \subseteq \Bbb R$ and $B = \{ x \in \Bbb Q \mid x^2 \lt 2 \} \subseteq \Bbb Q$.  Walk through your reasoning with each set in mind to see what's happening.  $A$ has a supremum in $\Bbb R ~(\sqrt 2)$ but $B$ has no supremum in $\Bbb Q$ (because $\sqrt 2 \notin \Bbb Q$).